# How can I modify certain sections of a txt file trough C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to access and modify certain sections of a txt file from C#.

I have a Game.txt file which currently has only two rows in it and each row has only 5 words. Below is what I have:

Row 1: Rick Sanchez rick@gmail.com sword fire

Row 2: John Smith john@gmail.com shield water

I want to check if the content of this Game.txt file has the email rick@gmail.com and if it does then I want to rewrite/replace the word sword with helmet. Below is what I tried and I am currently stuck. Any help is appreciated:

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\folder\Game.txt");
for (int i = 0 ; i < words.count() ; i++)
    {
       if(words[i].Contains("rick@gmail.com"))
       {
          string[] rowDetail = words[i].Split(' ');
          rowDetail[3]=helmet; // This only writes it in RAM; not in Game.txt file

    // Alternatively I tried below but it seems to overwrite on top of the entire txt file and wipe out all data:

          FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\folder\Game.txt");    
          Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("helmet");
          fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
          fs.Close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Use a structured, serializable/dserializable data transfer format like JSON.

Comment: @DanielMann good and well, but clearly that isn't an option -@erol has a text file. It's not json

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` has a corresponding [File.WriteAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar I know. I'm suggesting an alternate design. We don't have details on the requirements of the application and the provenance of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you're homework is meant to be, but this will replace all occurances of Sword with Helmet, if the email is found

```
 string words = File.Read(@"C:\folder\Game.txt");
   
 if((words.Contains("rick@gmail.com"))
 {
    words = words.replace("sword","helmet");
 }

 FileStream fs = File.WriteAllText(@"C:\folder\Game.txt",words);
```

Comment: I would assume that `sword` should be replaced with `helmet` only in the line with `rick@gmail.com`. OP wasn't precise about it, but it seems logical.

Comment: You're probably right, it is a long way from compiling, feel free to submit an edit, you have enough reputation. Otherwise, it helps the op get on their way

Comment: that is correct sword should be replaced with helmet only in the line/row that it also has rick@gmail.com